# Google Script App to Toggle between showing and hiding COLUMNS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Help!

I am trying to write a script for a toggle button that will show (and then hide again) hidden cells in Google Sheets, and I am having trouble. Can anyone please help me?

I want to place a button (already made) in the sheet (already inserted) and assign a script (I can get to this point) that will toggle between hiding/showing columns B to F.

Please help. I am lost!

Answer (score 0):

As you know, there is no method to check if the column is hidden or not. But there is a workaround here.

#### Code:

```
function toggleColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  if (scriptProperties.getProperty('hidden') == 'false') {
    scriptProperties.setProperty('hidden', true); 
    sheet.hideColumns(2,5);
  }
  else {
    scriptProperties.setProperty('hidden', false);
    sheet.showColumns(2,5); 
  }
}
```

We can store the state into script properties. Just click the button at least twice to initiate the value. Then the succeeding clicks on the button should toggle the showing/hiding of columns B-F.

#### Sample:

[image: sample]

#### 1st Click:

[image: output1]

#### 2nd Click:

[image: output2]